# Select 1st and 2nd Record before record X

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008-12

I have table:

```
InteractionKey char(18)
dEventTime datetime
SeqNo int
cEventData1
```

There will be multiple entries per InteractionKey - dEventTime only goes out to the Seconds and SeqNo is incremented if two entries occur on the same second.

What I need to do is select the First and Second record BEFORE the record where

`cEventData1 = 'Disconnect'`

The final product will give me a count of occurrences grouped by cEventData1.

I am currently using a cursor (will update with cursor source momentarily) I would like to use a CTE - but I really struggle with understanding them...

Any ideas would be appreciated!

**Update with Data Sample**

```
INTERACTIONKEY      dEventTime          SeqNo   cEventData1

100186322420130722  2013-07-22 11:50:49.000     1   EnterPassword
100186322420130722  2013-07-22 11:50:49.000     2   CheckPassword
100186322420130722  2013-07-22 11:50:49.000     3   Attendant Disconnect
```

The result of the query would ideally tell me - : NOTE The Action column here can be simply 'Attendant Disconnect'  as Action

```
cEventData1     Action                   Count
CheckPassword   Attendant Disconnect        1
```

**Here is the query I ended up going with based upon the below answer**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.InteractionKey,
        DisconnectTime = t1.dEventTime,
        PreviousEventTime = t2.dEventTime,
        PreviousEvent = t2.cEventData1,
        t2.SeqNo
FROM    IVRHistory t1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 t2.dEventTime, t2.SeqNo, t2.cEventData1
            FROM    IVRHistory t2
            WHERE   t1.InteractionKey = t2.InteractionKey
            AND     t1.dEventTime >= t2.dEventTime
            AND     t1.SeqNo > t2.SeqNo
            AND     t2.cEventData1 <> 'Attendant Disconnect'
            ORDER BY t2.dEventTime DESC, t2.SeqNo DESC
        ) t2
WHERE   t1.cEventData1 = 'Attendant Disconnect'
```

Comment: Can you give some mock data as an example of what you want?

Comment: @zimdanen Looking into that now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this using [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  t1.InteractionKey,
        DisconnectTime = t1.dEventTime,
        PreviousEventTime = t2.dEventTime,
        PreviousEvent = t2.cEventData1,
        t2.SeqNo
FROM    T t1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 2 t2.dEventTime, t2.SeqNo, t2.cEventData1
            FROM    T t2
            WHERE   t1.InteractionKey = t2.InteractionKey
            AND     t1.dEventTime > t2.dEventTime
            ORDER BY t2.dEventTime DESC
        ) t2
WHERE   t1.cEventData1 = 'Disconnect';
```

This will give you the two records immediately preceeding the disconnect event. If you need more than two records if there are duplicate times you can use `TOP 2 WITH TIES`.

Without your sample input and output I am guessing a bit, but from what you have said your final aggregate would be:

```
SELECT  t2.cEventData1,
        Occurances = COUNT(*)
FROM    T t1
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 2 t2.dEventTime, t2.SeqNo, t2.cEventData1
            FROM    T t2
            WHERE   t1.InteractionKey = t2.InteractionKey
            AND     t1.dEventTime > t2.dEventTime
            ORDER BY t2.dEventTime DESC
        ) t2
WHERE   t1.cEventData1 = 'Disconnect'
GROUP BY t2.cEventData1;
```

Comment: Firstly - Thank you! Secondly, this is actually giving me the  the 4th and 5th records - I am troubleshooting it currently.